# Is ngOnInit too late to initialise an EventEmitter var inside a component in Angular?

Tags: angular, initialization, ngoninit, angular-event-emitter

I tried with the following child component class

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class Child implements OnInit {
  @Output() send: EventEmitter<string>;
  public constructor(){}
  public ngOnInit() {
    send = new EventEmitter<string>();
  }
  public onEventXYZ() {
    this.send.emit('hello');
  }
}
```

and in the parent template i am referencing the above component as

```
<child (send)="handleSend($event)"></child>
```

it resulted in this error: `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined...` on page load. When i later, on a friend's suggestion, moved the EventEmitter initialization from ngOnInit to the constructor, everything worked fine.

So, it too late to initialize component vars inside ngOnInit ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're subscribing to the event received in the parent component. When you use the event binding signature (`(send)="handleSend($event)"`) in the template, you don't have to explicitly subscribe to the event.

Try the following

parent.component.html

```html
<child (send)="handleSend($event)"></child>
```

parent.component.ts

```js
handleSend(event: any) {
  console.log(event);
  // no subscription is needed here
}
```

And as for the `EventEmitter` initialization, you could do it in the definition line. It doesn't affect the code.

child.component.ts

```js
export class Child implements OnInit {
  @Output() send: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  public constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: Michael D, i know it works with inline definition too, but i'm trying to find out, why is it too late to initialize the EventEmitter type var in ngOnInit ?

Comment: @oomer: That depends when you're calling `emit` on the `send` variable. The `ngOnChanges` hook is triggered before `ngOnInit`. So if you were to emit something inside `ngOnChanges`, you'll get the undefined error. There is no wrong in initializing it in the definition like I showed.

Answer (score 0):

## Angular subscribes sooner

Initializing in `ngOnInit` doesn't work because Angular subscribes to the `EventEmitter` before `ngOnInit` is called. And it cannot subscribe to it if it doesn't exist.

But initializing inline and initializing in the constructor works.

## Some unrelated resources that elaborates my answer a little more:

**Disclaim: I could not find any direct documentation to address this topic peculiarly**

- [Angular change log](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CHANGELOG_ARCHIVE.md#bug-fixes-91)
- [Angular lifecycle hooks which show that ngOnInit is the second executed method after instantiation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)
- [Angular issue that somehow is related to this topic](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3664)
- [Where I guess Angular subscribe to the `@Output` listener](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/render3/instructions/listener.ts#L219)
- [Another function which I guess is involved in this process](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/render3/instructions/listener.ts#L40)
- [Discord discussion link about this exact topic](https://discord.com/channels/748677963142135818/750098681876709517/989788062777217084)

Comment: i can't access the discord link you shared.

Comment: @oomer Do you have an discord link? If yes are you join in Angular discord server? if Yes, IDK what I should say except that I do have an [Angular project in GitHub](https://github.com/kasir-barati/my-angular-journey/blob/main/src/app/media/media.component.ts#L50) which I tried to elaborate it. I hope this will help you.

Comment: is this your observation about event emitter subscribing behavior (that it happens before ngOnInit is called) or did you read it somewhere in the docs ?

Comment: @oomer I am trying to add some references. But I could not complete it, yet. I hope newly added ref gave you a better understanding. BTW I will add a good ref if I find